# WakaTime API Key Validation Issue in Excel

Tags: excel, wakatime

I am encountering an issue while trying to integrate WakaTime with Excel for the first time. After installing the Excel installer for WakaTime, I attempted to enter the API key. However, I received a warning stating, "Please enter a valid API key."

Upon manual verification, I observed that the input field for the API key seems to be truncating the key, accepting 5 characters less than the actual key length. I have searched extensively for a solution but haven't found any relevant information.

I am looking for the assistance to resolve this issue.